# Segmentation fault creating project in Rails, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 Server to set up a Ruby on Rails development environment. I followed this guide to install it http://www.rubypluspl.us/2012/06/ubuntu-1204-ruby-on-rails-development.html

After step 4, where it says that the environment should be set up, I run

```
$ rails new app
```

This causes this error to occur

```
run  bundle install
/home/jarek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:318: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

Followed by this huge block of text.

http://pastebin.com/Ps8bWxFG

I haven't been able to find any solutions for this. An answer I tried for a similar issue on StackOverflow is the reason I had to do a fresh install. Can anyone help me get Ruby up and running? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you install all libraries listed in:

```
rvm requirements
```

just in case clean rvm packages:

```
rm -rf $rvm_path/usr
```

and then reinstall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```